# Insert value from textbox into 2 different table ms-access

Tags: ms-access

I have 2 types of table in my database. 
Project and Services table.
Both table have projectNo and address field.
I have created 3 form, one for project department (view only), one for services department (view only) and another form is combination of first form and second form and will be use for data entry form for sale department.
So, in data entry form there will be 2 projectNo and address textbox in the form because 1 for project table and another one for services table.
Is there any suggestion on how can I fill both table field by single textbox value?

Table structure.
project - projectNo; order; engineer; address; 
services-projectNo; warranty; warrantyEnd; address;

Answer (score 1):

Short answer is yes. You can use vba code to update the field in the second table after updating the textbox in one of the forms. However the key question is why do you have address field in both tables if they are going to be the same all the time.

What is the relationship between Project and services? Are all the services going to have the same address as their projects? Are services going to be shared by multiple projects?

The solution may be simply to delete address from one of the tables or make the service form a subform of the project form

Comment: Thank you @Sheils . address field in both table is needed because service team can only view data from service form same goes for project team they can only view data from project form (data privacy purpose). Yes they will have the same address. for example project team produce a bike after project team send it to customer address then they will have no more relation with the customer. Then when customer need maintenance then it will be the task for service team to visit the customer address.

Comment: Project team are not suppose to know anything about warranty and service team are not suppose to know anything about who's the engineer is.   Yes service team going to be shared by multiple project. I should create the vba code in which form ? do you have any template or any reference for the code?

Comment: If the answer is "Yes they will have the same address" then you definely should delete the address field from one table. Then use query as the record source for your forms. For example, if you remove address field from tblService you can use the query "Select tblservice.projectNo; warranty; warrantyEnd; address from tblService Inner join tblProject on tblservice.projectNo=tblproject.projectNo

Comment: It's better to get the table logic right and avoid store duplicate information than using vba to cover for the shortfall

Comment: The code if you must use is:-

Dim strSQL as String
strSQL= "Update project set address=" & Me.Address & " WHERE projectNo=" & Me.projectNo

Comment: The code if you must use is:-

Dim strSQL as String
strSQL= "Update project set address=" & Me.Address & " WHERE projectNo=" & Me.projectNo

Currentbd.Execute strSQL

Insert this in the after update event of the Address textbox in the service form

This should work but as mentioned before the correct solution would be to remove the duplication